# DbVisualizer inserts a paramter into my Oracle DB Function call

Tags: dbvisualizer

I'm trying to write an Function in an Oracle database.  When i'm in the function editor and attempt to run it, DbVis inserts an additional parameter.

```
@call [dbvis - v0] = SP_GET_ANNUAL_SALES_HISTORY( [dbvis - v1], 'DAL', '00105315', '2013' );
@echo returnValue = [dbvis - v0];
@echo p1 = [dbvis - v0];
```

Then I get this error:

```
... Physical database connection acquired for: JdaTest
10:36:40  [@CALL - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_GET_ANNUAL_SALES_HISTORY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
10:36:40  [@ECHO - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  returnValue = null
10:36:40  [@ECHO - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  p1 = null
... 3 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [2 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

This is my function.  It's my first foray into stored procedures.  At this point, I'm just trying to getting it to run and delivery some results.  hte Return type is a Type I also created.  It's 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "SAPMGR"."ANNUAL_SALES_HISTORY" is Varray(12) of number'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SAPMGR"."SP_GET_ANNUAL_SALES_HISTORY" (loc_in IN varchar2,item_in IN varchar2,year_in IN varchar2)
RETURN annual_sales_history
AS
        yearStart       Date;
        yearEnd         Date;
        start_date      sales_history.start_date%TYPE;
        qty             sales_history.quantity%TYPE;
        ash             annual_sales_history;        

        cursor c1 is
        select start_date,QTY 
        from sales_history
        where item = item_in
          and loc = loc_in
          and start_date between yearStart and yearEnd
        order by item, loc, start_date;

BEGIN
        Loop
                fetch c1 into start_date, qty;
                exit when c1%notfound;
                ash(extract(month from start_date)) := qty;

                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ash' || ' ' || ash(0) || ' ' || ash(1) || ' ' || ash(2) || ' ' || ash(3) || ' ' || ash(4) || ' ' || ash(5)|| ' ' || ash(6) || ' ' || ash(7));      
        End loop

        commit;
        close c1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);        

        RETURN ash;
 END;
```

What is [dbvis - v1] and how do I get rid of it?  Or, please show me where I'm leaving something out maybe

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I received mail from DbVisualizer that their editor does not recognize custom data types, and that was what I was attempting.  So, stay with native types, and you're ok.